# Get class of selected svg element in d3

Tags: d3.js

How do i use instance of `<rect>` of a `svg` to get it's class?

I have to remove lines which have same class as the clicked `<rect>`.

I tried using `selection.class()` which obviously didn't work nor did `selection.classed()` help.

Comment: `selection.attr('class')`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

when using d3 I have found this works

```
selection.attr("class");
```

Comment: been super long time, but this doesn't seem to work anymore

Comment: still should, looking at the docs here: https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/v3.0.0/README.md#selection_attr